# dyld[8922]: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.dylib

Tags: python, bash, macos, terminal

I tried to update my python to python 3.10. i played around with brew, with unlink older python.

suddenly.. i got this and i never can call brew , python or anything

```
Last login: Fri Oct 29 13:21:52 on ttys000
dyld[964]: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.dylib
 Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/gawk/4.1.4_1/bin/gawk
 Reason: tried: '/usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libreadline.7.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libreadline.7.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/Cellar/readline/8.1.1/lib/libreadline.7.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libreadline.7.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libreadline.7.dylib' (no such file)
-bash: awk: command not found
-bash: sed: command not found
-bash: dirname: command not found
-bash: dirname: command not found
-bash: dirname: command not found
-bash: dirname: command not found
```

'''

i am not a programer and i am in the middle of learning python data science.. so i really need guidance for this,

Help me, guys..

i am in mbp M1 , running osx 12 Monterey

Thank you.